# SSRS Date from Date Parameter cannot be selected if Dataset query returns null or empty

Tags: date, reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

I am using parameters **PeriodType** where depending on what will choose will set Dates for **DateFrom**, **DateTo** parameters like in the following example:

Period Type (DateFrom, DateTo)

- Yesterday - **06/24/2019 - 06/24/2019**
- Today     - **06/25/2019 - 06/25/2019**
- ThisWeek  - **06/24/2019 - 06/30/2019**
- LastWeek  -  **06/17/2019 - 06/23/2019**
- ThisMonth - **06/01/2019 - 06/30/2019**
- Range - **Manually will pick dates from DateFrom and DateTo**

When I select for example **"This Month"** period, **DateFrom** and **DateTo** receive dates and Report displays the results.
[Result of the selected period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOOZa.png)
When I select **"FromTo"** period, my dataset query which generates dates returns null (tried even to return nothing from the procedure) and Date Parameters remain empty and contain calendar icon for choosing dates manually. If I select the dates and run the report, nothing happens and date parameters become blank.
[Blank DateFrom and DateTo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLgrL.png)

Default Values for **DateFrom** and **DateTo** is set the same as available values. I even tried to set to No default value but the issue remains the same.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Are you using the Specify Values settings for DateFrom and DateTo?  Another way might be to utilize a nested IIF statement.

Comment: Values for DateFrom and DateTo comes from query where returns dates based on the selected period from PeriodType parameter. Query returns NULL (and tried to return nothing) when PeriodType is FromTo (Range). I am returning NULL or nothing in order to be able to select manually dates.

Comment: If you are also populating the parameters' **Available Values**, then only NULL will be available.

Comment: I removed Available values and left only Default value which receives from the query and this helped. This even helped to leave the date parameters as date and not as drop down list. Thanks for the tip, this solved the issue.

Comment: I was in a hurry and now noticed that after the initial select of period type, the dates are getting as should, but after that if i change the period type, dates always remain the same from the first selection.